# Is there cases supporting a victim of a crime suing a debt collector for being harassed by a debt collector?

Tags: harassment, debt

If victims assistance is being held back, can I tell a debt collector to collect from the victims assistance program, or would I be better off telling them to accept something I grew (and painted), since debts can be collected through market value of something?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all.  I'm especially confused as to how the title and body are related.  Can you add more context?  Bear in mind, though, that we cannot provide legal advice on your specific situation; you'd have to consult a lawyer professionally.

Comment: Anyone being harassed by a debt collector should study local laws around debt collection and harassment.  Generally, in the US, they have to stop calling you if you tell them to stop calling you.

Answer (score 1):

A debt collector wants your money, not a suggestion to talk to someone who isn't going to give them any money. If you really do want them to stop contacting you, you can send them a cease and desist letter (i.e. in writing), per [15 USC 1692c(c)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/1692c), they must stop contacting you except to say that they will not contact you, and to inform you that they are suing you. It won't make them go away, it just escalates the matter.

Comment: isn't that admission of receipt if you file a cease and decist?

Comment: You don't file it with the courts, you mail it tot he debt collector. If you do send a C&D letter, it is evidence that you at least got *some* communication from them, if that is important.

Comment: so if they don't they're just trying to remind you that you may owe them something?